# Using I2C_master library AVR

Tags: function, pointers, avr, i2c

I am using I2C_master library for AVR, Communication works fine, but I have little problem, how can I get data.

I am using this function

```
uint16_t i2c_2byte_readReg(uint8_t devaddr, uint16_t regaddr, uint8_t* data, uint16_t length){

devaddr += 1;
if (i2c_start(devaddr<<1|0)) return 1;

i2c_write(regaddr >> 8);
i2c_write(regaddr & 0xFF);

if (i2c_start(devaddr<<1| 1)) return 1;

for (uint16_t i = 0; i < (length-1); i++)
{
    data[i] = i2c_read_ack();
}
data[(length-1)] = i2c_read_nack();

i2c_stop();

return 0;}
```

And now I need to use received data, and send it by UART to PC

```
    uint8_t* DevId;

    i2c_2byte_readReg(address,REVISION_CODE_DEVID,DevId,2);
    deviceH=*DevId++;
    deviceL=*DevId; 
    UART_send(deviceH); 
    UART_send(deviceL);
```

I think that I am lost with pointers. Could you help me, how can I get received data for future use? (UART works fine for me in this case, but it sends only 0x00 with this code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `i2c_2byte_readReg` takes as a third argument a pointer to the buffer where the data will be written. Note that it must have size bigger than the forth argument called `length`. Your `DevId` pointer doesn't point to any buffer so when calling the function you've got an access violation.

To get the data you should define an array before calling the function:

```
const size_t size = 8;
uint8_t data[size];
```

Then you can call the function passing the address of the buffer as an argument (the name of the array is converted into its address):

```
const uin16_t length = 2;    
i2c_2byte_readReg(address, REVISION_CODE_DEVID, data, length);
```

Assuming that the function works well those two bytes will be saved into `data` buffer. Remember that `size` must be bigger or equal to `length` argument.

Then you can send the data over UART:

```
UART_send(data[0]); 
UART_send(data[1]);
```